# Fonts are not seen in the PDFMake

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

For PDFMake, I want to use Chinese fonts in the PDF. Therefore, I have downloaded Google Noto font `NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf` and then converted it to `.ttf` online and then by converting it to base64, I added it in the `vfs_fonts.js`. But still font is not shown correctly.

[image]

What am I missing?

```
pdfMake.fonts = {
      NotoSansCJKscRegular: {
            normal: "NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.ttf"
      }
};

var docDefinition: {
    content: [
        {
            text: "通用规范汉字表",
            font: "NotoSansCJKscRegular"
        }  
    ]
};

pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
```

Also, is there any better way so that I can add any language text in the pdf file in the pdfMake?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You've added the font to the vfs fonts. That's good, but you still have a few steps to go :

```
async addCustomFontsToVfs() {
    /** Including the fonts in the vfs file. */
    pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
    const fontNames = ['light', 'normal', 'bold'];
    const fontArray = await Promise.all(fontNames.map(async (fontName) => [
        fontName,
        fetchFontFileFromAssets(`assets/afep/fonts/${fontName}.ttf`))
    ]));

    
    const pdfMakeFonts = {};

    fontArray.forEach(([fontName, fontBase64]) => {
        if (!fontBase64) {
            throw new Error(`Font couldn\'t be fetched.`);
        }
        pdfMake.vfs[`${fontName}.ttf`] = fontBase64;
        pdfMakeFonts[fontName] = `${fontName}.ttf`;
    });

    /** Define fonts from vfs */
    pdfMake.fonts = {
        // Default font
        Roboto: {
            normal: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
            bold: 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
            italics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
            bolditalics: 'Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
        },
        fontFromAsset: pdfMakeFonts, // ours
    };
}
```